# Is there a way to take a screen shot in macOS programmatically?

Tags: swift, macos, unity-game-engine, objective-c++, unity3d-native-plugins

It seems like all the old frameworks have been deprecated (e.g. `CGWindowListCreateImage`) in favor of `ScreenCaptureKit`. Unfortunately it only offers streaming. Is there a simpler way I can get a screenshot of the user's display?

Given displayId, x, y, width and height, I need a function to return the byte data of the desktop screen capture image. It's for a Unity3d native plugin.

I've tried ScreenCapture kit but it's just not right for this use case.

Everything else is deprecated.

Comment: You can still use `CGDisplayCreateImage` can't you?

Comment: I don't know why Apple does this, but they often deprecate APIs with no exact replacement. I'd bet on `CGDisplayCreateImage` being safe to use for quite a while, as there's *a lot* of existing software that uses it. They probably won't be removing it any time soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is, in WWDC 23, ScreenCaptureKit API were introduced to capture screenshots programmatically.

Please refer here :

**What’s new in ScreenCaptureKit**

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10136/?time=586